# Why is this if/then statement returning as true?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a rather ugly service job that runs through a legacy database and compares it to our production database:

```
if (vendorContract.Item.Where(x => x.ItemNumber == contractItem.Item_Number) != null)                        {
 var oldDbContractItem = vendorContract.Item.Where(x => x.ItemNumber == contractItem.Item_Number).First();
                            // check to see if there were changes
                            if (oldDbContractItem.DateStamp != vendorContractItem.Date_Stamp)
                            {
                                oldDbContractItem.Update(vendorContractItem);
                            }
                        }
```

I will get an error on `var oldDbContratItem`, "Sequence contains no elements", yet I just did a != null check. This must be simple, what's going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the test against `null` you are doing:

```
vendorContract.Item.Where(x => x.ItemNumber == contractItem.Item_Number) != null
```

That will *always* be true; That will always return at least an empty sequence... never a `null`.

You might be meaning to test that its length is greater than 0?

There's an easier way, though, IMO. Call `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `First()` and leave out the pre-test completely. Then instead, test if the result of `FirstOrDefault()` is `null`.

```
var oldDbContractItem = vendorContract.Item
  .Where(x => x.ItemNumber == contractItem.Item_Number).FirstOrDefault();
if(oldDbContractItem != null) //would be null if there are no items
{
  // check to see if there were changes
  if (oldDbContractItem.DateStamp != vendorContractItem.Date_Stamp)
  {
    oldDbContractItem.Update(vendorContractItem);
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 17):

If I could teach people just one thing about LINQ it's this: the value of a query expression is *an object that represents the query*, not *the results of the query*.  Fundamentally that's your problem; you're treating the query as its results. A query isn't a result any more than a restaurant is a club sandwich. A restaurant is a device which produces club sandwiches; a query is a device that produces results.

Comment: I like this answer more than mine, from a fundamentals POV.

Answer (score 2):

Because your query returned a container, it just happened to be empty, the null check is on the return not what the return contains.

try this instead...

```
if (vendorContract.Item.Where(x => x.ItemNumber == contractItem.Item_Number).Any())
{
  .....
}
```

Comment: Note, in your specific case, @Andrew Barber has the more elegant solution (as you are wanting the first element if it exists anyway), my solution is for just testing the sequence contains something.

Comment: +1 This would be the way to go when, for instance, you would be dealing with (potentially) multiple items in a result sequence, instead of just one.

Comment: @Andrew: `foreach` would be the way to go if you are dealing with potentially multiple items.  Running the query a second time just to call `Any` is silly (or worse, if the query is against a shared data store, it introduces a race condition).

Answer (score 1):

Don't run the query twice.  It's inefficient and may introduce a race condition into your code.  Also, your logic is much better supported by either using `IEnumerator<T>` directly, or with a `foreach` loop.

Use either:

```
var result = vendorContract.Item.Where(x => x.ItemNumber == contractItem.Item_Number).GetEnumerator();
if (result.MoveNext) {
    var oldDbContractItem = result.Current;
    // ...
}
```

or

```
foreach (var oldDbContractItem in vendorContract.Item.Where(x => x.ItemNumber == contractItem.Item_Number)) {
    // ...
    break;
}
```

Comment: +1 for noting that the original code was needlessly running the query twice.

Answer (score 0):

After using a fix from the accepted answer, you can further debug the LINQ situation (if need be) by using the following steps.  LINQ is an exciting technology but takes a while to wraps ones' head around it - a bit of a paradigm shift I would say. [Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175731/4175800#4175800) hit the nail on the head because he likely helped build the stuff!

**Debugging Steps for LINQ**

1. To deal with the issue of no results from the second statement change `.First()` to `.FirstOrDefault()`  If nothing is found it will return the default value of the data type - if the data type is a class it will return a null value. Your second statement should then work with a null check too and without error.
2. Then you can debug your LINQ statement to find out why it's doing what it does.

   - if using LINQ to SQL, Intellisense in Visual Studio 2010 will show you the SQL generated when you hover over a query variable (not the result of a query). If you need the visualizer for VS 2008 [it's here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx)
   - Similarily if you're using LINQ to Entity Framework, you can get the generated SQL using the [visualizer plugin here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/99468ece-689b-481c-868c-19e00e0a4e69).
3. I always take the generated SQL from these tools, paste it directly into a query window and run it there. It will show you the empty set you're getting back and if that's a problem you can further debug it in this manner of visualizing the generated statements.

Comment: This is not actually solving anything. The problem is that his test for an empty sequence is wrong. You're just masking the bug.

Comment: @Yuliy: the accepted answer also suggested `FirstOrDefault` as a step in debugging. It's not masking anything but rather making the process more manageable.

Comment: ....but you're right if you noticed I was focusing on the second code statement more than the first, not about the truth test. I will leave these tool hyper-links here in case they prove useful to somebody debugging a LINQ situation.

Answer (score 0):

A sequence with no elements is still an object.

Answer (score 0):

`Where` can return a non-null value, but still resolve to a sequence containing no elements.  In your failing statement you are using something else, which is `Where().First()`.  That will be null if the sequence from `Where` is indeed empty.

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between `null` and an empty sequence (e.g. something similar to `new List<T>()`). What you want to do is to use `Any()` to check whether the sequence contains any elements, or rather replace `First()` with `FirstOrDefault()`, which returns `null` if the sequence contains no element. (If you use that, make sure that `null` is not a valid value that could be returned by `First()`).